# How do I fetch all Git branches?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I cloned a Git repository containing many branches. However, `git branch` only shows one:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

How would I pull all the branches locally so when I do `git branch`, it shows the following?

```
$ git branch
* master
* staging
* etc...
```

Comment: Also discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-do-i-clone-all-remote-branches-with-git

Comment: This question shows how to get all branches after using the `--single-branch` setting when cloning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714159/how-do-i-undo-a-single-branch-clone (`git fetch --all` will never work if you've specified only one branch!)

Comment: You will not see that output ever because the asterisk represents the branch that is currently checkout out. Since you can only have one branch checked out at once, you can have only one asterisk on the left of your branch listing.

Comment: The top-ranked answer below misses the OP's intent. I recommend that you look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/72156/342839 instead. `git checkout -b <branch>` seems like the most likely answer.

Comment: I saw a lot of answers but none of them mentioned what I think is probably the easiest way to do what you want:

`git clone --bare <repo url> .git ` (notice you need to add "--bare" and ".git" at the end to clone the repo as a "bare" repo), then `git config --bool core.bare false` (sets the "bare" flag to false), then `git reset --hard` (moves the HEAD to current HEAD on the repo). Now if you `git branch` you should see all branches from the repo you cloned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Comment: @GabrielFerraz Why don't you write this as an answer?

Comment: @GabrielFerraz Then you are abusing the comment functionality on Stack Overflow. Users can upvote your comment but not downvote.

Comment: `git fetch origin` will do.

Comment: `git pull origin '*:*'`

Answer (score 3066, accepted):

#### TL;DR answer

```sh
git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
git fetch --all
git pull --all
```

(It seems that pull fetches all branches from all remotes, but I always fetch first just to be sure.)

Run the first command only if there are remote branches on the server that aren't tracked by your local branches.

#### Complete answer

You can fetch all branches from all remotes like this:

```
git fetch --all
```

It's basically a [power move](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch).

`fetch` updates local copies of remote branches so this is always safe for your local branches **BUT**:

1. `fetch` will not **update** local branches (which **track** remote branches); if you want to update your local branches you still need to pull every branch.
2. `fetch` will not **create** local branches (which **track** remote branches), you have to do this manually. If you want to list all remote branches:
   `git branch -a`

To **update** local branches which track remote branches:

```
git pull --all
```

However, this can be still insufficient. It will work only for your local branches which track remote branches. To track all remote branches execute this oneliner **BEFORE** `git pull --all`:

```sh
git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
```

P.S. AFAIK `git fetch --all` and `git remote update` are equivalent.

---

---

Kamil Szot's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches#comment27984640_10312587), which folks have found useful.

> I had to use:
>
> ```
> for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track ${remote#origin/} $remote; done
> ```
>
> because your code created local branches named `origin/branchname` and
> I was getting "refname 'origin/branchname' is ambiguous whenever I
> referred to it.

Comment: Sorry.  I can't imagine that this is what the OP actually wants.  The 'pull' command is 'fetch+merge' and the merge part will overlay all the branches on top of one another - leaving one giant mess.

Comment: that fetch wouldn't create a new remote branch you still need to check it out with `git checkout -b localname remotename/remotebranch`

Comment: does git fetch, fetches changes from all branches I track ? or I need to be on that branch that I want to fetch from, and other changes won't be fetched for other tracked branches ? (if that makes sense)

Comment: I had to use 
    `for remote in \`git branch -r\`; do git branch --track ${remote#origin/} $remote; done` 

because your code created local branches named origin/branchname and I was getting "refname 'origin/branchname' is ambiguous whenever I referred to it.

Comment: I don't know if I'm using a different version of GIT, but I had to amend the script to `git pull --all; for remote in \`git branch -r | grep -v \>\`; do git branch --track ${remote#origin/} $remote; done`. The change strips out HEAD.

Comment: For the Windows folks: `for /F %remote in ('git branch -r') do ( git branch --track %remote) && git fetch --all && git pull --all`

Comment: This does not work at all for my version of git: 1.8.1.2

The effect was to create a dozen branches named "origin/$x" which were all tracking the local branch "master".

Comment: There is a slight difference between `git fetch --all` and `git remote update` First is that git fetch --all was added in v1.6.6. Second fetch --all will pull from all remote repos. see the commit 9c4a036b3 on github. https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c4a036b34acef63ab754f0e27e5e54bd9d9a210

Comment: The solution of @kim3er worked for me. The problem with all snippets is that they don't work when you have slashes or spaces in the branch names. When you need to write bulletproof bash scripts you should use the `while read` trick as this `git branch -r | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; d` and quote the variable expansions!

Comment: @Max: had to make a small tweak
`for /F %r in ('git branch -r') do ( git branch --track %r) && git fetch --all && git pull --all`

Comment: It creates branches with 'origin/'

Comment: Please update your answer with the comments. It is misleading and creates branches with `origin/`

Comment: I had an issue with the color output in my terminal for the various `git branch -r` commands to find all the various branches. Use `git branch -r --no-color` to prevent not valid branch names on terminals supporting color codes.

Comment: `git pull --all` just does nothing: *"You asked to pull from the remote '--all', but did not specify a branch"*

Comment: Stupid to execute the command before checking the comments, I believed the accept mark and the upvotes ... stupid. Now have to delete the repo and clone from scratch.

Comment: I've fixed now the answer as per comments, as I was badly burned by this as well. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: isn't `fetch  --all` meant to fetch all remotes? at least it does not work for me (does not fetch new remote branches)

Comment: `git pull` only merges into the current branch, even with `--all`.  So it won't update other tracking branches besides the current.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger fetch all remotes is not the same as fetch all branches.  Most people only have one remote (origin) so fetch --all rarely does anything different.

Comment: @TedBigham exactly why I _asked_ since the question was to fetch all branches, not all remotes!

Comment: my Powershell script for updating all new untracked branches and pulling them: `git branch -r | grep -v "\->" | foreach {git branch --track $_.Substring($_.IndexOf("/") + 1)}; git pull --all`

Comment: Regarding "it seems that pull fetches all branches...". It's practically on the front cover of any git manual that pull does a fetch/merge.  Why don't you confirm this and remove the parenthetical guess? Might throw in a mention that you can configure "pull" to "fetch rebase".

Comment: The question was very clear: fetch five branches from one remote, not fetch one branch from five remotes. I don't understand how this answer was accepted.

Comment: This variation excludes tracked branches and master branch : `for remote in $(git branch -r | grep -v -e "\->" -e master); do git branch --track ${remote#origin/} $remote; done`

Comment: Yet again goes to show just how _hostile_ the Git command line frontend is towards its users. And it goes to show that Git was never designed with cross-platform use in mind, as evidenced by the ridiculous use of shell commands, which will of course vary by shell. Originally being a concoction of binary executables and shell scripts the target audience is clear and has never changed. Even nearly 13 years since initial release.

Comment: Read this and never write and suggest others `git fetch` followed by  git pull` https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/1114926

Comment: `git fetch --all` and `git remote update` are almost the same. However, `git remote update` by default fetches the remote specified by `remotes.default`. If this is not set (which I believe by default it is not) then it will fetch all. Best to just use `git fetch --all` as its behavior is consistent.

Comment: Is it possible to have a git alias for that one liner? If I put it in my .gitconfig file i get "fatal: bad config line X"

Comment: I am trying to do the same, `git config --global alias.fa 'branch -r | grep -v ">" | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done'` does just display git branch command definition

Comment: As a casual Git user, this answer was just a teeny bit too advanced for me. I really appreciated the distinction its author was trying to make, but the details were lost on me. For anyone else like me, the [Atlassian Git Tutorial on `git fetch`](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch) explains the background information really well, so now this answer makes sense to me. +1!

Comment: No pull is required to update tracked branches. It could be done via index update. At least we achieve this by `git fetch origin master:master`, for example. This allows to update index without checking branches out.

Comment: What do you mean by the words "power move" linking to the docs for `git fetch`? (Serious question, I don't understand how it is one...)

Comment: color fonts also pipe into after grep which causes: `fatal: '?[31morigin/dev?[m' is not a valid branch name`

Comment: `git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | sed "s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g" | while read remote; do shopt -s extglob && git branch --track "${remote##!(/)/}" "${remote##+( )}"; done` worked for me

Comment: Please also note that (according to the man pages installed on my machine with git version 2.36.0) `git fetch -a` is actually short for `git fetch --append` rather then `git fetch --all`, meaning there is no short flag for fetching from all remotes. (The append flag adds fetched content to the FETCH_HEAD, rather then replacing it). I used to run `git fetch -taf` which didn't do what I wanted.

Comment: Also be aware that you do not always need to create a local branch in other to 'use' a remote tracking branch. You can view remote tracking branches using `git branch -r` and hard reset to, merge or rebase wrt eg origin/somebranch directly. 
Creating all of these local branches may not make sense. In my workflow, I rarely use more then two local branches at the same time.

Comment: Can you explain what does this `"s,\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z],,g"` mean?

Comment: @Lucas, A **sed** command, like `s/foo/bar/` replaces "foo" with "bar".

This one uses `,` instead of `/`.

The final `g` means replace *all* rather than just one.

`\x1B\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]` is a *regular expression*.  It matches the Escape character (`\x1B`), followed by an open square bracket (`\[`), followed by zero or more (`*`) digits or semicolons (`[0-9;]`), followed by a letter (`[a-zA-Z]`).

The whole RE matches sequences that make the terminal change the colour of following text.

The command replaces these with empty string (`,,`), i.e. deletes them.

Comment: I upvoted this answer but my upvote is locked, no, this is wrong, how could you do this to my main branch!!!

Comment: For Windows 10 the command is just fine in git bash and works with no error.

Answer (score 1241):

To list remote branches:

```bash
git branch -r
```

To checkout a remote branch as a local branch:

```bash
git checkout -b local_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for when I found the question above. I suspect many people looking for how to pull a remote branch definitely don't want to merge the branch into their current working copy, but they do want a local branch identical to the remote one.

Comment: Even if the branch is not visible locally, I can do `git checkout remotebranchname`and it works. what's the difference with your solution?

Comment: Its default behaviour now. Wasn't the case on older git versions. Using `git checkout remotebranchname` used to just create a new **unrelated** branch that is named _remotebranchname_.

Comment: The accepted answer does something fundamentaly different and to be frank I don't even understand why its the accepted answer

Comment: The OP asked for all branches.  This answer only does one.

Comment: That's perfect for one branch at a time. Just if someone can edit it with the new command (but the old one is still working ;)

Comment: A co-worker created a branch and made a PR. I was tasked with updating the PR and was having issues checking out the remote branch with its work onto my local machine. This solution worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: `fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'develop' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'origin/temp' which can not be resolved as commit?`.That's result when I run answer script, what's the problem?

Comment: Not my script, idk. Leave a comment under the answer?

Comment: What if I want to merge, not checkout? `git checkout -b LocalName origin/remotebranchname`

Comment: Merge what? A remote branch?

Comment: I think in the main question is written how to fetch all git branches, not a single one, one by one, maybe, therefore, this is not the selected answer

Comment: It is best practice to update the origin with `git remote update` and then list the remote branches with `git branch -r`

Comment: If you're doing this with newer versions of Git, you'll want to use `git switch -c local_branch_name origin/remote_branch_name`

Answer (score 222):

You will need to create local branches tracking remote branches.

Assuming that you've got only one remote called `origin`, this snippet will create local branches for all remote tracking ones:

```
for b in `git branch -r | grep -v -- '->'`; do git branch --track ${b##origin/} $b; done
```

After that, `git fetch --all` will update all local copies of remote branches.

Also, `git pull --all` will update your local tracking branches, but depending on your local commits and how the 'merge' configure option is set it might create a merge commit, fast-forward or fail.

Comment: This robustifies the solution against branch names containing shell metacharacters (as per pinkeen's comment on the other answer), and avoids spurious error output: git branch -r | grep -v -- ' -> ' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote" 2>&1 | grep -v ' already exists'; done

Comment: Are you sure that `git pull --all` will update all local tracking branches?  As far as I can tell it only updates the current branch from all remotes.

Comment: Did this.  Local branches matching remote branches were not created.  What is the git command that simply says "pull all remote branches creating local ones if they do not exist?"

Comment: @JosephK perhaps your remote is not called `origin`? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335346/5353461) which will work on all remote names.

Comment: @TomHale It was "origin," but thanks for your answer - though crazy that much is necessary to do what should be one or maybe two flags.  I am now trying gitless, to try to avoid the insanity of some aspects of git.

Answer (score 166):

If you do:

```
git fetch origin
```

then they will be all there locally.  If you then perform:

```
git branch -a
```

you'll see them listed as remotes/origin/branch-name.  Since they are there locally you can do whatever you please with them.  For example:

```
git diff origin/branch-name
```

or

```
git merge origin/branch-name
```

or

```
git checkout -b some-branch origin/branch-name
```

Comment: Just found this page on google... this was the actual type of answer I was seeking.

I tried the first command but received an error:
[$ git fetch --all origin
fatal: fetch --all does not take a repository argument] ---

Using "git fetch --all" seems to do the trick.

Thanks for the lead!

Comment: Fixed (eliminated `--all`)

Comment: `git fetch -all` fetches all branches of all remotes.  `git fetch origin` fetches all branches of the remote `origin`.  The later is what the OP was asking.

Comment: `--all` means "all remotes", not "all branches of a given remote". The latter is implied by any fetch from a remote.

Comment: OP asked for a solution enabling "branch", not "branch -a".

Comment: This is not the way to pull all branches into local repo, from remote repo.

Comment: Actually I have a case where a clones repository was lacking some (unmerged) branches, and your solution did not add the missing branches. `git branch -r` displays them, however.

Comment: This does not bring down the branches

Answer (score 132):

```
$ git remote update
$ git pull --all
```

This assumes all branches are tracked.

If they aren't you can fire this in Bash:

```
for remote in `git branch -r `; do git branch --track $remote; done
```

Then run the command.

Caution: mind the warnings below (all remotes will track the same local branch `main`).

Comment: When I try that I still get the same result as above.

Comment: Same as @JacobLowe, I got the error, but it worked anyway; 'fatal: A branch named 'origin/master' already exists.'

Comment: This is ugly as it will try to create a branch for `->` which will likely exist in the output of `git branch -r` as ` origin/HEAD -> origin/master`

Comment: Moreover, it doesn't work. I get output: `Branch 'origin/quote-filenames' set up to track local branch 'master'.`  The desired output is: `Branch 'quote-filenames' set up to track remote branch 'quote-filenames' from 'origin'.`

This is **backwards**, setting the origin to track the remote. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335346/5353461) for a fix.

Comment: just what I needed. Since I switched Mac's, even after I cloned the repo I wasn't able to checkout other remote branches and `git fetch` wouldn't work. So the lesson here is that you need to track the remote branches. Gracias!

Comment: A small improvement to exclude error on HEAD branch: **for REMOTE in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`; do git branch --track ${REMOTE}; done** .

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer

Comment: The command to track remote branches does not work at all. It created a bunch of branches that all pointed to the last master commit.

Comment: I second what @TomHale and @thomas-glaser observed:

`Branch 'origin/app1' set up to track local branch 'master'.` 
[..]
`Branch 'origin/app10' set up to track local branch 'master'.`

Comment: DON'T ENTER THIS COMMAND, IT WILL MESS YOUR REPO

Answer (score 102):

The Bash `for` loop wasn't working for me, but this did exactly what I wanted. All the branches from my origin mirrored as the same name locally.

```
git checkout --detach
git fetch origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

See [Mike DuPont](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3939046/mike-dupont)'s comment below. I think I was trying to do this on a Jenkins Server which leaves it in detached head mode.

Comment: That produces `fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository` after a simple clone. Have to detach head first. I did this with `git checkout <SHA>`

Comment: My Solution using this is ```git checkout --detach # detach the head```
and then ```git fetch origin \'+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* ```

Comment: This one worked for me, except I also use the --tags parameter.  I wish there was a standard, simple front end for git, the number of simple things in git that need 10-plus stack overflow answers is ridiculous!

Comment: @kristianp Have you checked out Ungit or GitKraken?

Comment: @dragon788 I've been using SourceTree for a git GUI, but I was really talking about a simpler command-line for scripting tasks.

Comment: @kristianp ahh, I get you. You might look at something like easygit, https://people.gnome.org/~newren/eg/

Comment: You could also probably do a `git clone <repo_URI> .git` to just setup a bare repo without content. Then execute the OPs command: `git fetch origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`.

Comment: @kristianp maybe try ungit - the philosophy is exactly what you've mentioned!

Comment: This is the only answer that works even when `remote.<remote>.fetch` is setting to something restrictive.

Comment: This helped after unshallowing - other answers didn't work for my repository which I originally pulled in a shallow mode.

Comment: ***This does not track the remote branches. This is a wrong answer: Do not use this. This answer only copies the remote branches to your local repo.***

Comment: @basickarl I don't follow your comment. I checked `.git\refs\heads` as well as `.git\refs\remotes\origin` and everything is fine. If you want to get the latest of a branch, you need to switch to that branch via `git checkout branchname`. You then do `git pull origin branchname` to get the latest for the checked-out branch from origin.

Comment: @Pegues I think a lot of confusion resides in how tracking works and it's role in updating your local repo. You are by all means correct, the command in this post does do a fetch, but if you are not tracking the branches it won't fetch them. I guess my comment for more for beginners. - Also the way you mentioned to update a branch is 100% legit, but there are other ways of doing it aswell^^

Answer (score 61):

Use `git fetch && git checkout RemoteBranchName`.

It works very well for me...

Comment: This is the new best answer, y'all. I don't know if maybe this wasn't possible before, but recent versions of Git at least will notice that you are trying to checkout a remote branch and will automatically set up the local tracking branch for you (and you don't need to specify `origin/branch`; it suffices to say only `branch`).

Comment: This does not answer the original question: "How would I pull all the branches locally?" It is pulling them one-by-one, which isn't scalable.

Comment: This was the only answer which allowed me to pull remote branches in every situation I've encountered

Answer (score 49):

When you clone a repository all the information of the branches is actually downloaded but the branches are hidden. With the command

```
$ git branch -a
```

you can show all the branches of the repository, and with the command

```
$ git checkout -b branchname origin/branchname
```

you can then "download" them manually one at a time.

---

However, there is a much cleaner and quicker way, though it's a bit complicated. You need three steps to accomplish this:

1. First step

   create a new empty folder on your machine and clone a mirror copy of the .git folder from the repository:

   ```
   $ cd ~/Desktop && mkdir my_repo_folder && cd my_repo_folder
   $ git clone --mirror https://github.com/planetoftheweb/responsivebootstrap.git .git
   ```

   the local repository inside the folder my_repo_folder is still empty, there is just a hidden .git folder now that you can see with a "ls -alt" command from the terminal.
2. Second step

   switch this repository from an empty (bare) repository to a regular repository by switching the boolean value "bare" of the git configurations to false:

   ```
   $ git config --bool core.bare false
   ```
3. Third Step

   Grab everything that inside the current folder and create all the branches on the local machine, therefore making this a normal repo.

   ```
   $ git reset --hard
   ```

So now you can just type the command `git branch` and you can see that all the branches are downloaded.

This is the quick way in which you can clone a git repository with all the branches at once, but it's not something you wanna do for every single project in this way.

Comment: Upvoted for mention of hidden branches. helped me understand the local branch tracking immensely.

Comment: Its a good answer, but the question implies something for every day use. Its not practical to clone the repository everytime.

Comment: Why the reset creates all the branches locally?

Comment: @Z.Khullah it's not the reset that creates all the branches, but the clone --mirror. Unfortunately for us, that also creates a bare repo, which is what steps 2 and 3 change.

Answer (score 42):

You can fetch all the branches by:

```
git fetch --all
```

or:

```
git fetch origin --depth=10000 $(git ls-remote -h -t origin)
```

<sup>The `--depth=10000` parameter may help if you've shallowed repository.</sup>

---

To pull all the branches, use:

```
git pull --all
```

---

If above won't work, then precede the above command with:

```
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

as the `remote.origin.fetch` could support only a specific branch while fetching, especially when you cloned your repo with `--single-branch`. Check this by: `git config remote.origin.fetch`.

After that you should be able to checkout any branch.

See also:

- [How to fetch all remote branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39957760/55075)
- [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699/55075)

---

To push all the branches to the remote, use:

```
git push --all
```

eventually `--mirror` to mirror all refs.

---

If your goal is to duplicate a repository, see: [Duplicating a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/) article at GitHub.

Comment: Awesome...I tried everything else before your solution in this page. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used shallow cloning (`depth=1`) and the config also specified one specific branch for `fetch` - the `depth=1000` parameter was the fix that helped me to checkout a specific remote branch

Comment: `pull --all` doesn't pull all the branches, but all the remotes

Comment: Nice trick with the config, though! Would fetch them all, all the time

Comment: I checked config as you wrote, still only works with current branch. Looks like all answers here do not work for me...

Answer (score 33):

I usually use nothing else but commands like this:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout --track origin/remote-branch
```

A little shorter version:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -t origin/remote-branch
```

Comment: Thanks, simple and to the point.  I was skeptical that git required so many for loop scripts for that...

Answer (score 32):

If you are here seeking a solution to get all branches and then migrate everything to another Git server, I put together the below process. If you just want to get all the branches updated locally, stop at the first empty line.

```
git clone <ORIGINAL_ORIGIN>
git branch -r | awk -F'origin/' '!/HEAD|master|main/{print $2 " " $1"origin/"$2}' | xargs -L 1 git branch -f --track 
git fetch --all --prune --tags
git pull --all

git remote set-url origin <NEW_ORIGIN>
git pull
<resolve_any_merge_conflicts>
git push --all
git push --tags
<check_NEW_ORIGIN_to_ensure_it_matches_ORIGINAL_ORIGIN>
```

Comment: Very helpful; exactly what I needed. The only thing I had to change was in the second line, added single quotes around 'HEAD' and 'master'; probably because I'm using zsh. Thanks!

Comment: This is basically doing the following: (1) Obtaining the actual names of  remote branches [not head, not master]; (2) Completely telling Git to track them [not all solutions do this]; (3) Fetching and pulling everything from these branches [including tags]; (4) Setting a new origin and walking through pushing absolutely everything up. Again, most of the other solutions fail to move all pieces. This does it all.

Comment: I removed the antipattern of running grep then awk and condensed the grep commands into the awk command. Thanks [tripleee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee)!

Comment: Read this and never write `git fetch git pull` https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/1114926

Comment: Git `pull` does indeed do a `fetch` first but it's easier to tell if the problem is from the `fetch` part of `pull` or the subsequent `merge` part of `pull` when `fetch` is executed independently.

Comment: **Secret sauce is the second line** (sometimes I run this on a repo to create all remote branches locally): `git branch -r | awk -F'origin/' '!/HEAD|master|main/{print $2 " " $1"origin/"$2}' | xargs -L 1 git branch -f --track`

Answer (score 32):

### You don't see the remote branches because you are not tracking them.

1. Make sure you are tracking all of the remote branches *(or whichever ones you want to track)*.
2. Update your local branches to reflect the remote branches.

---

### Track all remote branches:

*Track all branches that exist in the remote repo.*

**Manually do it:**

*You would replace `<branch>` with a branch that is displayed from the output of `git branch -r`.*

```
git branch -r
git branch --track <branch>
```

**Do it with a bash script:**

```
for i in $(git branch -r | grep -vE "HEAD|master"); do git branch --track ${i#*/} $i; done
```

**Lazy way (this can create a mess due to merge conflicts, be careful):**

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

### Update information about the remote branches on your local computer:

*This fetches updates on branches from the remote repo which you are tracking in your local repo. This does not alter your local branches. Your local git repo is now aware of things that have happened on the remote repo branches. An example would be that a new commit has been pushed to the remote master, doing a fetch will now alert you that your local master is behind by 1 commit.*

```
git fetch --all
```

### Update information about the remote branches on your local computer and update local branches:

*Does a fetch followed by a merge for all branches from the remote to the local branch. An example would be that a new commit has been pushed to the remote master, doing a pull will update your local repo about the changes in the remote branch and then it will merge those changes into your local branch. This can create quite a mess due to merge conflicts.*

```
git pull --all
```

Comment: Single character variables are confusing.  I suggest 
    `for remoteBranch in $(git branch -r | grep -vE "HEAD|master"); do git branch --track ${remoteBranch#*/} $remoteBranch; done`

Comment: By using `xargs` instead of a `for` loop you won't need any variable at all.

Comment: @bjhend Could you write an example and I'll be happy to update!

Comment: @basickarl I'd replace the loop with something like `git branch -r | grep -vE "HEAD|master" | xargs -I remoteBranch -n 1 echo ...remoteBranch...` with `echo` replaced by the `git branch` command but I see now that the removal of the remote in remoteBranch will require some sort of `sed` command maybe making it more complicated.

Comment: This seems to have created a mess for me. I believe what needs to be mentioned is that before each round of commands one needs to checkout an appropriate branch.

Answer (score 20):

I believe you have cloned the repository by:

```
git clone https://github.com/pathOfrepository
```

Now go to that folder using cd:

```
cd pathOfrepository
```

If you type `git status` you can see all:

```
   On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

To see all hidden branch types:

```
 git branch -a
```

It will list all the remote branchs.

Now if you want to checkout on any particular branch just type:

```
git checkout -b localBranchName origin/RemteBranchName
```

Answer (score 18):

Make sure all the remote branches are fetchable in `.git/config` file.

In this example, only the `origin/production` branch is fetchable, even if you try to do `git fetch --all` nothing will happen but fetching the `production` branch:

```
[origin]
fetch = +refs/heads/production:refs/remotes/origin/production
```

This line should be replaced by:

```
[origin]
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Then run `git fetch` etc...

Comment: To inspect:  `git config --get remote.origin.fetch` and then to (destructively) set it: `git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'`

Comment: or modify config text file in .git directory, worked for me

Answer (score 14):

After you clone the master repository, you just can execute

```
git fetch && git checkout <branchname>
```

Comment: simple. and worked to get a branch from remote origin

Comment: This does not answer the original question: "How would I pull all the branches locally?" It is pulling them one-by-one, which isn't scalable. Consider the case of 100 branches.

Answer (score 11):

Just these three commands will get all the branches:

```
git clone --mirror repo.git  .git     (gets just .git  - bare repository)

git config --bool core.bare false

git reset --hard
```

Comment: This is actually the root of OP's problem. If cloned right, he wouldn't need to do a `pull --all`. But if still needed, then the other answer bellow, by @Johnno Nola, assuming all branches are tracked, mixed with this answer, is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

### **How to Fetch All Git Branches Tracking Single Remote.**

This has been tested and functions on Red Hat and Git Bash on Windows 10.

---

**TLDR:**

```
for branch in `git branch -r|grep -v ' -> '|cut -d"/" -f2`; do git checkout $branch; git fetch; done;
```

**Explanation:**

The one liner checks out and then fetches all branches except HEAD.

List the remote-tracking branches.

```
git branch -r
```

Ignore HEAD.

```
grep -v ' -> '
```

Take branch name off of remote(s).

```
cut -d"/" -f2
```

Checkout all branches tracking a single remote.

```
git checkout $branch
```

Fetch for checked out branch.

```
git fetch
```

---

Technically the fetch is not needed for new local branches.

This may be used to either `fetch` or `pull` branches that are both new and have changes in remote(s).

Just make sure that you only pull if you are ready to merge.

---

### **Test Setup**

Check out a repository with SSH URL.

```
git clone git@repository.git
```

**Before**

Check branches in local.

```
$ git branch
* master
```

**Execute Commands**

Execute the one liner.

```
for branch in `git branch -r|grep -v ' -> '|cut -d"/" -f2`; do git checkout $branch; git fetch; done;
```

**After**

Check local branches include remote(s) branches.

```
$ git branch
  cicd
  master
* preprod
```

Answer (score 10):

Looping didn't seem to work for me and I wanted to ignore origin/master.
Here's what worked for me.

```
git branch -r | grep -v HEAD | awk -F'/' '{print $2 " " $1"/"$2}' | xargs -L 1 git branch -f --track
```

After that:

```
git fetch --all
git pull --all
```

Comment: A variation of this is the correct answer, but this one does not work in all edge cases. Also, the branch names can be funky. So I did the following: git branch -r | grep -v HEAD | grep –v master | awk -F'origin/' '{print $2 " " $1"origin/"$2}' | xargs -L 1 git branch -f --track ; git fetch --all ; git pull --all ; AND THAT DID THE TRICK!

Comment: A stylistic improvement to avoid the `grep | awk` [antipattern](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep): `git branch -r | awk -F 'origin/' '!/HEAD|master/{` ...

Answer (score 10):

For Windows users using PowerShell:

```
git branch -r | ForEach-Object {
    # Skip default branch, this script assumes
    # you already checked-out that branch when cloned the repo
    if (-not ($_ -match " -> ")) {
        $localBranch = ($_ -replace "^.*?/", "")
        $remoteBranch = $_.Trim()
        git branch --track "$localBranch" "$remoteBranch"
    }
}; git fetch --all; git pull --all
```

Comment: This works with branches with / in the name:

`git branch -r | ForEach-Object {
    # Skip default branch, this script assumes
    # you already checked-out that branch when cloned the repo
    if (-not ($_ -match " -> ")) {
        $localBranch = ($_ -replace "^.*?/", "")
        $remoteBranch = $_.Trim()
        git branch --track "$localBranch" "$remoteBranch"
    }
}`

Answer (score 6):

Here's something I'd consider robust:

- Doesn't update remote tracking for existing branches
- Doesn't try to update `HEAD` to track `origin/HEAD`
- Allows remotes named other than `origin`
- Properly shell quoted

```bash
for b in $(git branch -r --format='%(refname:short)'); do
  [[ "${b#*/}" = HEAD ]] && continue
  git show-ref -q --heads "${b#*/}" || git branch --track "${b#*/}" "$b";
done
git pull --all
```

It's not necessary to `git fetch --all` as passing `-all` to `git pull` passes this option to the internal `fetch`.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312587/5353461).

Comment: I'm trying to replicate this in another scripting language (Typescript) but don't understand the bash syntax `${b#*/}`  - can someone explain the meaning please?

Comment: Found a useful resource https://devhints.io/bash which shows `${STR#*/}` expands to the full path of STR (i.e. b in the above code).

Comment: Also note that from a Windows cmd prompt, `git branch -r --format='%(refname:short)'` will output quote marks ('), so use double-quotes : `git branch -r --format="%(refname:short)"`

Answer (score 6):

Be careful while playing with git, go step by step.

```
$ git remote update  //This will update your local
$ git branch -a      //This will list all the branches(After updating you can now 
see the new branch in the list)
$ git checkout your_branch_name
```

Answer (score 5):

Set alias: (based on the top answer)

```
git config --global alias.track-all-branches '!git fetch --all && for remote in `git branch -r`; do git branch --track ${remote#origin/} $remote; done && git fetch --all'
```

Now to track all the branches:

`git track-all-branches`

Answer (score 5):

```
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾fetch/clone‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾↓   |‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾checkout‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾↓   
|‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾pull‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾↓
Remote repository (`origin`) <=> Local repository <=> Index <=> Workspace
↑_________________push_______________|   ↑____commit____|  ↑____add_____|
```

```sh
# 拉取远程仓库所有分支信息 → 本地仓库
# fetch all remote repository branch meta → local repository
git remote set-branches origin '*'
git fetch -v

# 把所有远程分支数据搞到本地
# fetch all remote repository branch data → local repository
git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
git fetch --all
git pull --all
```

Comment: This is answer worked for me!

Comment: Please note https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: @mirekphd Feel the love from the East ^o^

Answer (score 5):

you can fetch all braches by this one line command like this:

```
git fetch --all && git pull --all && git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little script to manage cloning a new repo and making local branches for all the remote branches.

You can find the latest version [here](https://gist.github.com/tstone2077/8380f7862b00b6234963):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Clones as usual but creates local tracking branches for all remote branches.
# To use, copy this file into the same directory your git binaries are (git, git-flow, git-subtree, etc)

clone_output=$((git clone "$@" ) 2>&1)
retval=$?
echo $clone_output
if [[ $retval != 0 ]] ; then
    exit 1
fi
pushd $(echo $clone_output | head -1 | sed 's/Cloning into .\(.*\).\.\.\./\1/') > /dev/null 2>&1
this_branch=$(git branch | sed 's/^..//')
for i in $(git branch -r | grep -v HEAD); do
  branch=$(echo $i | perl -pe 's/^.*?\///')
  # this doesn't have to be done for each branch, but that's how I did it.
  remote=$(echo $i | sed 's/\/.*//')
  if [[ "$this_branch" != "$branch" ]]; then
      git branch -t $branch $remote/$branch
  fi
done
popd > /dev/null 2>&1
```

To use it, just copy it into your git bin directory (for me, that’s `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git-cloneall`), then, on the command line:

```
git cloneall [standard-clone-options] <url>
```

It clones as usual, but creates local tracking branches for all remote branches.

Answer (score 4):

If you have problems with `fetch --all` then track your remote branch:

```
git checkout --track origin/%branchname%
```

Answer (score 4):

**TLDR**
It is likely a bad idea to create a local branch for each remote tracking branch. These different types of branches serve different purposes and local branches are normally created based on their need. `git branch` shows local branches `git branch -r` shows the remote tracking branches. `git branch -a` shows both. You can update all remote tracking branches with an appropriate fetch command. That should usually be all you need.

---

After scrolling through the existing answers I see two kinds: those simply answering the question asked, rather than suggesting a different approach. And those suggesting a different approach without explaining why. Here is my attempt to explain a bit more.

There are actually three kinds of branches a usual git repository needs to deal with. These three kinds of branches serve different purposes. In short:

- **remote branches**: These are the branches as they exist in the remote repository. You will never read from remote branches directly. All reading of remote branches happens through gits so called "remote tracking branches"
- **remote tracking branches**: git keeps local snapshots of the remote branches which are most accurately called "remote tracking branches". They are updated when you call `git fetch` or `git pull` (which does a fetch). You can often get away with using the remote tracking branches without creating local branches out of them.

  For example:

  ```
  git merge origin/master
  ```

  will merge the remote tracking branch `origin/master` into the current local branch without requiring you to create a local copy of it first. This means: there is a remote tracking branch called `origin/master` which is a snapshot of the branch called `master` as it exists on the remote repository called `origin`. And this command will merge it into the current checked-out local branch. You may want to do a fetch before performing operations like this.
- **local branches**: these are manually created snapshots of certain points in history (often based on remote tracking branches, at least at first). They are much more static than the other kinds and will *really* only change when you *manually* change them. One by one. You will likely want a local branch if you want to view its contents in your working-tree (project directory) or when you want to add commits to it.

Once you are done with a local branch (and published its contents) you may consider deleting it. That way you do not need to keep it up to date. After all, a fetch will not update the current local branch, and a pull will only update the current checked-out local branch. In other words: you should only create local branches when you need them, and you should probably delete them when you no longer do.

It is probably not accurate to say that 'some branches are hidden by default'. Rather the `git branch` command was created to show you the "local branches". You can use `git branch -r` to list the remote tracking branches and `git branch -a` to show both the local branches and the remote tracking branches. These two different types of branches serve a different purpose and you are not likely to need a local branch for each remote tracking one.

Also note that is is generally a bad idea to create local branches whose names begin with the name of a remote followed by a slash (eg creating a local branch called "origin/master" tends to be a bad idea since its name conflicts with the name of the remote tracking branch).

In the context of updating branches, it does make sense to discuss different flavours of fetch commands:

- `git fetch`: updates only the remote tracking branches whose remote matches the one used in the "upstream" of the current checked out branch. If the checked out branch does not have an upstream set, this falls back to fetching from a remote called "origin" if it exists. This command is the easiest, and is sufficient most of the time.
- `git fetch --all`: updates all remote tracking branches regardless of the remote they belong are snapshotting from.

I am especially fond of

```
git fetch -tf --all
```

Which will also always update (and override if needed) all tags, including tags not reachable from the remote branches.

Answer (score 2):

We can put all branch or tag names in a temporary file, then do git pull for each name/tag:

```
git branch -r | grep origin | grep -v HEAD| awk -F/ '{print $NF}' > /tmp/all.txt
git tag -l >> /tmp/all.txt
for tag_or_branch in `cat /tmp/all.txt`; do git checkout $tag_or_branch; git pull origin $tag_or_branch; done
```

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the error message **'fatal: A branch named 'origin/master' already exists.'**, you may try my solution:

```sh
git branch -r | grep -v '\->'  | grep -v `git branch | awk '/\*/ { print $2; }'`| while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#origin/}" "$remote"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Have tried many ways, only this one is simple and works for me.

```sh
for branch in $(git ls-remote -h git@<your_repository>.git | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's:refs/heads/::')
do
  git checkout "$branch"
  git pull
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Perl version of the one-liner provided in the accepted answer:

`git branch -r | perl -e 'while(<>) {chop; my $remote = $_; my ($local) = ($remote =~ /origin\/(.*)/); print "git branch --track $local $remote\n";}' > some-output-file`

You can run the output file as a Shell script if you'd like.

We deleted our Stash project repository by accident. Fortunately someone had created a fork right before the accidental loss. I cloned the fork to my local (will omit the details of how I did that). Once I had the fork fully in my local, I ran one one-liner. I modified the remote's URL (origin in my case) to point to the target repository we were recovering to:

`git remote set-url origin <remote-url>`

And finally pushed all branches to origin like so:

`git push --all origin`

and we were back in business.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by Learath2, here's what I did after doing `git clone [...]` and `cd`-ing into the created directory:

`git branch -r | grep -v master | awk {print\$1} | sed 's/^origin\/\(.*\)$/\1 &/' | xargs -n2 git checkout -b`

Worked for me but I can't know it'll work for you. Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote add origin https://yourBitbucketLink

git fetch origin

git checkout -b yourNewLocalBranchName origin/requiredRemoteBranch (use tab :D)
```

Now locally your `yourNewLocalBranchName` is your `requiredRemoteBranch`.

Comment: This fetches, but does not *pull*, all branches.  Pull also merges after fetching.
The `checkout` only creates *one* local branch, not all.

Answer (score 0):

```
for branch in $(git branch -r); do 
  echo "BRANCH: $branch --> ${branch#*/}"; 
  git fetch origin ${branch#*/}; 
done
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

For Visual Studio Users, On Package Manager console:

```
git branch | %{ git fetch upstream; git merge upstream/master}
```

Comment: What is the point of the pipe?  How does this pull *all* branches.