# How to get the last commit ID of a remote repo using curl-like command?

Tags: git, git-commit

I want to get the last commit ID of the **remote** git repo.

The command `git rev-parse HEAD` works for a locally-cloned git repo, but I want to get it from the original GIT repo by a CURL command or so.

Eg: I want to get the last commit ID of the git URL https://git.appfactorypreview.wso2.com/history/apiapp.git/.

How?

Answer (score 165):

try this command

```
git log --format="%H" -n 1
```

Comment: you can remove the pipe by doing `git log --format="%H" -n 1`

Comment: ```git log -n1 --format="%h"``` would provide the abbreviated commit hash.

Comment: This is wrong. In git 2.1.4 "%H" displays the local commit id, not the remote.

Comment: Where do you specified the remote URL?

Comment: This question has been modified since I answered it. For a remote repo, you can refer to the answer by @jszakmeister here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176736/1243123

Comment: The question was indeed modified, but just for readability. OP explicitly stated he did not have a local clone, and he wanted to use a `curl`-like solution.

Comment: There's also `git log | head -1`.

Comment: `git config --global alias.lc 'log -n1 --format="%h"'` makes it a global alias so you can type `git lc` (last commit). I often use abbreviated commit hashes for untagged/unstable release builds.

Answer (score 56):

Another way, without using git log:

`git rev-parse HEAD`

Answer (score 53):

I think what you want is this:

```
git ls-remote $URL HEAD
```

If `HEAD` doesn't exist in the remote repository, then you likely want:

```
git ls-remote $URL refs/heads/master
```

Note that in the first instance, `HEAD` is going to point to the default branch to checkout in the repository.  You need to be sure that's the branch you want, or just use the second form and specify the one you want (replace `refs/heads/master` with the name of the branch you want: `refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME`.

Comment: You cannot use `HEAD`, because it is a pointer to the current branch. But in a bare repo it does not exists a `HEAD`.

Comment: It's not true that it *never* exists.  Case and point: `git ls-remote git://github.com/jszakmeister/vimfiles.git HEAD`.  In a bare repo, it tells Git which branch to checkout as the default branch.  It is true that you cannot count on it existing.  So, in that case you should use an appropriate refname.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `git ls-remote` for this. Because I get a `'Unauthorized access for repository apiapp.git'` I use as example torvalds linux-repo.

```
$ git ls-remote --heads git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
6d15ee492809d38bd62237b6d0f6a81d4dd12d15        refs/heads/master
```

Answer (score 15):

The short hash of the last commit id is much more human readable (read: user friendly). For posterity, two ways to get the short hash of the last commit id:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD
```

OR

For getting short hash eg. `fb8a7de`

```
git log -n1 --format="%h"
```

For getting full hash eg. `fb8a7decf471abc61dc6e49616697d3bd722b96f`

```
git log -n1 --format="%H"
```

You can find more information on pretty-formats here https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Answer (score 7):

Simplest way I use:

```
git rev-parse origin/develop
```

Answer (score 5):

my answer would not help the OP because he's not on github, but I think I would mention it anyway because it uses `curl`, or `wget`, as the OP requested.

`wget -qO- http://api.github.com/repos/Ghini/ghini.desktop/commits/ghini-1.0`

`Ghini` is my repo, `ghini.desktop` is my repository, `ghini-1.0` is the branch I'm interested in. Replace them to fit your case.

the JSON answer is a dictionary, and the OP was interested in its `sha` field, but it contains a lot more information.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. Have a look at this :)
https://gist.github.com/AiyionPrime/40dbe9bd3be05bd68e25c5c0e1bfa92e#file-get_commit-sh

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch; git rev-parse origin/branch_name`

To be safe, run `git fetch` first.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here are correct so far.

The question was "How to get the last commit ID of a remote git repo".
But all Answers so far considered only a specific branch, usually the one that is currently checked out, or listed last commits for all branches.

I found this command to be helpful if you want to check for the last commit repository-wide:

```
# make sure you got all commits in all branches
git fetch --all
git pull --all
# print last commit id
git log --branches --format="%H" -n 1
```

Reference for getting all branches: [How do I fetch all Git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-do-i-fetch-all-git-branches/10312587#10312587)