# Travis configuration of phpcs for only current commit files

Tags: php, continuous-integration, travis-ci, devops, cd

I am configuring phpcs in Travis.
In order to check PHP code standard on commit push with travis CI.

I am using following script

```
script:
- phpcs --standard=PSR2  $(find ./ -name '*.php')
```

But this script checks each `.php` file. 
I need Travis to check only the current committed files.

Does someone has any solution for this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What you could try is the following:

get last commit id: ([How to get the last commit ID of a remote repo using curl-like command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176359/how-to-get-the-last-commit-id-of-a-remote-repo-using-curl-like-command))

```
git log --format="%H" -n 1
```

Then get files in last commit: ([How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit))

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r `git log --format="%H" -n 1`
```

You can see that previous command is used here. The first part before backtits needs a commit id to list files from. This commit id is found with the first command.

And then if you want only php files you can use grep :

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r `git log --format="%H" -n 1` | grep .php
```

Output on one of my php project:

```
app/Http/Controllers/BarterController.php
app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
app/Talk.php
resources/views/profiles/index.blade.php
resources/views/talks/show-comments.blade.php
```

Simply replace your command `$(find ./ -name '*.php')` with the one I gave above and it should work. Your command would become the following:

```
phpcs --standard=PSR2 $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r `git log --format="%H" -n 1` | grep .php)
```