# To find out last commit using jenkins pipeline script

Tags: linux, git, jenkins, devops

We are using below command to find out the last commit to the git

```
{ git log -1 --pretty=format:'%an'; echo "@xyzcompany.com, developer@xyzcompany.com"; } | xargs -I{} echo {} | sed 's/\n//'
```

Note: this command is working in CLI in jenkins workspace project.

How to inject this command in jenkins pipeline script??

Comment: You might want to have a look into this answer to simplify your command: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176626/437621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an `sh` to execute the command. If you are using declarative syntax (starting with `pipeline` instead of `node`) I'd suggest to do that in the `environment`, so you can read the result in all stages of your pipeline:

```
environment {
    COMMIT = sh(script: '{ git log -1 --pretty=format:\'%an\'; echo "@xyzcompany.com, developer@xyzcompany.com"; } | xargs -I{} echo {} | sed \'s/\n//\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
}
```

Or –if you use scripted syntax– you just declare a variable:

```
def commit = sh(script: '{ git log -1 --pretty=format:\'%an\'; echo "@xyzcompany.com, developer@xyzcompany.com"; } | xargs -I{} echo {} | sed \'s/\n//\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
```