# GIT - Get the last commit number id

Tags: git

The command `git log -1` gives information about the last commit. I am only interested in the number id. Can `git`  give me this, or do I have to use basic parsing on the output (I know how to do that)?

```
> git log -1
commit abcdefgh123456789000 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Author: ...
...
```

Comment: `git log --format="%H" -n 1`

Comment: Yes. My question can be indicated as a duplicated one.

Comment: There should be a box above the question asking if you're question is being answer by the marked duplicate.\

Answer (score 8):

Try using `rev-parse`:

```sh
git rev-parse HEAD
```

Comment: That is prettier than the solution given in the link of 0stone0.

Comment: [Should I answer duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). The `git rev-parse HEAD` is [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541370/5625547) in the marked duplicate.

Comment: @projetmbc A marked question doesn't mean you should blindly copy paste the first answer, but take a look at the other answers, this one is already mentioned there. Please upvote there to let other people know you prefer that solution.

Comment: @0stone0 I have not noticed it. ;-)