# Git Sync to upstream: Newly created branch not showing in my fork

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge, git-fork

I've two remotes - **origin** which points to my fork and **upstream** which points to company repo.

```
$git remote -v    
    origin  https://github.com/me/app.git (fetch)
    origin  https://github.com/me/app.git (push)
    upstream    https://github.com/company/app.git (fetch)
    upstream    https://github.com/company/app.git (push)
```

I forked before a month. and I've been pushing to origin and then raising a pull request to upstream. This was fine.

Now someone created a branch called "3D_Theory" in upstream and I want to first reflect that new branch in to my origin and then work off of that branch. But for some reason that branch is not reflecting in my origin.

I tried the following:

```
git remote show origin
>> does not list 3D_Theory

git remote show upstream
>> lists 3D_Theory
```

I tried:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git merge upstream/3D_Theory
```

But still I don't have that branch created on my fork. How can I get a new branch on upstream to reflect on my fork?

Thank you

None of the following similar problems helped me:

- [Git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945654/git-checkout-on-a-remote-branch-does-not-work)
- https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/
- [Can "git pull --all" update all my local branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38802129/4696809

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yay, I guess this worked.

```
git fetch upstream 3D_Theory:3D_Theory

git status

git push origin 3D_Theory
```

If you have a better solution please post it here and I'll try your solution and mark it as the better answer.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for some projects as you can get these errors if the repo is too big: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780221/git-push-failing-http-500-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-500-internal

So JamesP solution is actually the better way to do this.

Answer (score 8):

This can now be done via the GitHub UI. Select the Code<> tab and then click Branches. Add a new branch and change the source to the upstream repository. Select the new branch you want to add to your own fork and give the branch the same name as the upstream one.

From now on you can use the Sync Fork button to update your branch with the upstream one.

Comment: Other `git fetch upstream` didn't work for me. This approach in the GUI worked in adding a new branch to my fork from the original repository. Ty!

Comment: Best answer for me, as it's easier that the CLI solution

Comment: On GitHub UI I found I had to create a new branch in my fork with same name as upstream repository and then Sync fork

Answer (score 2):

Above will fetch only specified branch. There could be many newly branches created, if team size is large. This can be accomplished by following steps.

1. This will fetch all upstream branches & show on terminal

   `git fetch upstream`
2. This will push the current branch to upstream

   `git push origin`

Comment: This did not work for me after forking an organization's repo which contained a branch besides the default one. I was unable to get `git fetch upstream` to give me a reference to said non-default branch.

Comment: Before that add the "upstream": `git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORIGINAL_OWNER/ORIGINAL_REPOSITORY.git` and check with `git remote -v`