# Git push failing HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket, git-push

I have just setup git with bit bucket for my windows machine.

Git pull works properly, where as git push fails with below error.

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 174.03 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Any help is of great use.

Thanks

Comment: take a look it might help. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/unable-to-push-to-bitbucket-server-repository-779171784.html

Comment: it didn't work either

Comment: HTTP 500 is a server-side error. Are you using Bitbucket Cloud (hosted on bitbucket.org) or Bitbucket Server (self-hosted)?

Comment: It's bitbucket cloud. Moreover it's working with other fellow teammates. I have cross verified username too. I suspect something went wrong in configuration files

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Increase the global Git buffer size to the largest individual file size:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Or just for your repo:

```
cd your_repo
git config http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Comment: I had the OP problem with SourceTree, this answer has solved it for me.

Comment: I tried change the git password in windows credential store, without success, the issue was actually increasing the buffer size. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks! I resolved the issue by increasing the buffer size to 524288000 using the same command: `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

Answer (score 10):

I appreciate this is an old question, but the previous suggestions didn't work for me (I was getting the same error from `git fetch`). What worked for me was:

```
git gc
git fsck
```

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc | https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me because I had a **`no space left on device`** error...my server hard drive was **full** and could not write any files !

A short term option can be to [delete all temporary files](https://itsfoss.com/free-up-space-ubuntu-linux/) to free space and unfreeze the machine.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this same error showed up when I had old credentials saved in the git credentials store.

Updating the credentials in the ~/.git-credentials file solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know when in the future you'll be reading this question, but before trying every solution in here maybe check [the Github Status Page](https://www.githubstatus.com/), or the status page for your Git platform. I had a very similar problem on January 9, 2024 and tried a lot of stuff before realizing it was just a problem with Github itself, and all I could do was wait.

Comment: Currently I've got the Github failure when running 'git pull'

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when pushing a single commit of many large image files to GitHub. The solution was to undo this large commit and instead do five separate smaller commits and pushing each time. This way, less data is committed and pushed each time. I was able to push each of these batches successfully. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the above solution didn't solve the problem.
I've tried switch to ssh and found out that the problem were 2 big files, over 2GB, that weren't accepted by Github.

I excluded them in the .gitignore file, and then it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and solved it by updating the main and switching back to brunch. After this, I pushed again and the message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error when doing a `git push --mirror` when migrating a repository to GitHub.

To trouble shoot I pushed each branch separately and on one of them I got a better error message indicating that one of the commits was violating a repository ruleset.

Answer (score -2):

In my case the problem was the space in the server.
It had 0 bytes free. After I deleted a few big not important files, I was able to push.

Comment: Another user already provided this answer over four years ago. Please don't repeat answers.