# Why I can't delete files in git?

Tags: git, github

Why I can't delete file in git?? When I write `$ git rm Food101.mlmodel` 
git says - `fatal: pathspec 'Food101.mlmodel' did not match any files`. But when I write `git push` git say, that Food101.mlmodel is very large. How to fix it?

Comment: That means file  not exist in repo to delete. Try increasing you buffer

Comment: Can you see your file in the output from `git ls-files`?

Comment: Try this to push large files https://stackoverflow.com/q/44780221/1544977

Comment: @JerzyPawlikowski, I can't

Comment: It seems that the file is not in the repo so you cannot delete it. However `git push` sends commits rather than files. Is it possible that you are pushing multiple commits and in one of the commits you added large file and in the other commit you removed it?

Comment: @JerzyPawlikowski, yes

Comment: Then you can squash those commits using interactive rebase: `git rebase -i`

Comment: @JerzyPawlikowski, it doesn't work

Comment: It means that you have your file still in one or more commits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On first glance it seems you have misinterpreted what `git rm` does.

`Food101.mlmodel` is contained in atleast one commit.  That is, you have already called `git add Food101.mlmodel` and `git commit`.  The error / warning you are getting is when you then `git push`.

`git rm` will never remove a file from a previous commit.  It will only remove the file ready to commit a version of code that no-longer contains it.  That doesn't sound like what you want.

It sounds like you need to re-write your commit history so that it doesn't contain `Food101.mlmodel` at all.  To do this, I suggest you look for answers on how to "rebase" your commits to remove a file.  Or if it's only contained in your last commit or two you might prefer to simply use `git reset HEAD~` to step back a commit, and re-commit your changes minus the large file.