# Gitlab runner failure, HTTP 500 curl 22

Tags: git, docker, gitlab

We had been having troubles with gitlab runner for couple of days now. Whenever we try to deploy a commit, we are getting the following error (it's the full log):

> Running with gitlab-runner 10.8.0 (079aad9e)   on LST GitLab Runner
> 9db4eb2c Using Docker executor with image alpine:3.7 ...
>
> Pulling docker image alpine:3.7 ...
>
> Using docker image
> sha256:6d1ef012b5674ad8a127ecfa9b5e6f5178d171b90ee462846974177fd9bdd39f
> for alpine:3.7 ...
>
> Running on runner-9db4eb2c-project-2-concurrent-0
> via a7dcae9d7882...
>
> Fetching changes...
>
> HEAD is now at 142ba7a
>
> Merge
> branch '3378-new-payroll-export-lexware' into test
>
> error: RPC failed;
> HTTP 500 curl 22
> The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> ERROR: Job failed:
> exit code 1

It happens right after pulling docker image. We also tested it on different branches and different stages (we have test and deploy), all of them result with the same error.

Not sure if it's relevant, but we also cannot preform pull request from git repository. It fails with following error:

> RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
> Internal Server Error
>
> The remote end hung up unexpectedly

We tried switching to SSH instead of HTTP, but this also didn't work.
Could you please point us in right direction so we can solve it? What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole problem was connected to disk space. After logging in via SSH, we found out that docker container accumulated a huge log, that took all the space. We removed it and everything was fixed

I guess next step to avoid that problem in the future will be enabling docker to automaticly rotate the logs

Answer (score 0):

Check if Increasing the git buffer size to the largest individual file size of your repo solves the problem, for example-

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487332/737440

Also ensure that your server hard drive is not out of space.

Comment: `http.postbuffer` only works on pushes, not pulls.  In addition, the [Git documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/de93cc14ab7e8db7645d8dbe4fd2603f76d5851f/Documentation/config/http.txt#L195-L209) recommends against setting it unless you're sure you know you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP 500 error means that you've received an internal server error: the server has encountered a problem and can't continue.  Since it's insecure to tell the user what the problem is, the only indication of what went wrong will be in the logs.

If you're using a self-hosted GitLab instance, you should check the logs to figure out what's going on.  If you're using gitlab.com, you'd want to open a support ticket with them to see what's happening.

Note that it may be helpful (or not) to run the clone or fetch with `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1`, which will print information about the HTTP operation and any response that's being provided.

Comment: Thank you, we ended up opening ticket with gitlab.com
I wanted to try enabling trace, but since yesterday someone tried to fix gitlab by restarting it and now it returns error 502...

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, problem was solved. I'll post additional comment about how we fixed it

Answer (score 0):

In our case, it was Unicorn that was hung. Restarting it solved the issue but it took us a whole day to figure it out.