# IDEA: Update failed unable to access 'https://...git/': The requested URL returned error: 500

Tags: git, intellij-idea

When I try any operation with git in IDEA (pull, push, clone etc.), I receive message:

```
Update failed
unable to access 'https:...git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

But when I try it with terminal, it works. It's about all gitlab projects. It looks like something wrong with my IDEA, but I not shure. My Pycharm-projects in same gitlab directory works fine.

Comment: What does the GitLab logs says on the server side? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60100406/6309)

Answer (score 1):

There is HTTP 500 response, this is most likely something on the server-side.
There is known issue with random 500 errors returned by GitLab - e.g. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/66449

If not that exact issue (make sure you use the version that includes the fix), there might be other similar issues.

Please see the ticket for more:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243713

Answer (score 1):

There is [error](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-243713) in Idea when saved password is incorrect.

Clearing KeePass DB

[image]

(you can read how to do it in official documentation to Idea there https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html#set-passwords-for-git-remotes)

and entering password anew fixed this error for me.