# Git pull failing HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: windows, git, proxy

We are sitting behind a proxy thus git is configured as follows

```
[http "https://github.com"]
    proxy = http://:@webproxy.intra:8080
    sslBackend = schannel
    sslverify = true
[http "https://gitlab.com"]
    proxy = http://:@webproxy.intra:8080
    sslBackend = schannel
    sslverify = true
```

Remotes are set as follows

```
origin  https://gitlab.com/papanito/website.git (fetch)
origin  https://gitlab.com/papanito/website.git (push)
```

While pulling mostly worked, since a while I get the following error while fetching or pulling

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
fatal: error reading section header 'acknowledgments'
error: Could not fetch origin
```

> this is a different issue than [Git push failing HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780221/git-push-failing-http-500-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-500-internal)

This issue is probably related to the proxy (blocking?). Will further check but maybe somebody of you has some hints.

Answer (score 0):

I could workaround the issue by limiting the [depth](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt---depthltdepthgt).

```
git pull --depth 20
remote: Enumerating objects: 518, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (398/398), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (184/184), done.
Rremote: Total 323 (delta 171), reused 237 (delta 110), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (323/323), 4.84 MiB | 17.26 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (171/171), completed with 36 local objects.
From https://gitlab.com/wyssmann/website
```

While this is not a proper solution, it might help some in meanwhile.