Git: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500

git push origin main:main
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date

that's what is says i need help
i was not expecting the dum error

See if this question/answer offers help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780221/git-push-failing-http-500-curl-22-the-requested-url-returned-error-500-internal

You are probably trying to push large files to your git repo and need to setup LFS support.

https://git-lfs.com
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-git-lfs-with-bitbucket/
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs


Could be several reasons:

Server side issue
Network issue
Auth problem
Corrupt repo
Repo size limit.

I presume, that's because of size limitation issue, try to increase the buffer size:
# following sets the buffer to 500Mb
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

Reference: http.postBuffer

it said the same thing
