# Git Repository is not visible on docker hub for automatic build

Tags: github, docker, dockerhub, automatic-updates

I already have 2 automatic builds on hub.docker with Dockerfiles hosted on github. They are working great. My problem is now I want to use a Dockerfile in an github repository which is not my own but I am admin and member and have full access to. I can see several other repositories on the hub.docker page when I try to create a new automatic build. They are very similar to the one I want to use but the one I want to use is not listed there, although I have full access to it. I ready through do documentation from hub.docker and I also logged in and out. Further more I also delinked my github account and relinked it. (with write persissions). So my question is how can I make the other repository visible on hub.docker in order to create an automatic build?

Comment: in the worst case, you can try forking the repo.

Comment: I done it but in this case this repo is not in sync with the original one.

Comment: I know it's a workaround, but you can have it synced automatically with a cron job http://stackoverflow.com/a/28652472/3349358