# Github specific: How to automatically merge from the source repo I forked from?

Tags: git, github

In github, I fork repos I like to avoid having the repos "go away". I rarely make my own modification. However, I would like to keep my fork up to date with the source repo.

I know how to create pull requests from the source repo to my own repo using the github UI. However this is painful because:

1. new source branches are not automatically copied to my fork.
2. it is a manual process.
3. I have to remember to do this.

Ideally, I would like to configure my repos to automatically pull from the source repo on every commit to the source repo. The normal case for me is that there would never be a conflict because I rarely make changes - and when I do I create an entirely uniquely named branch.

I know I can pull from one remote repo, merge and push to another remote repo using my local machine. However, a local solution:

1. involves a lot of data going back and forth across my slow internet connection.
2. is not automatic, etc.

I would like to do merge entirely on the github computers.

Comment: I think you will need to set up a server to do this for you on a cron job. I do that with a Slackware server from https://hostus.us. You need to set the master repo as a fetch origin, and your repo as a push origin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can forks be synced automatically in gitHub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793062/can-forks-be-synced-automatically-in-github)