# Including Modified Django Package in Project

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to figure out how to include a modified package into a Django 2.2 project.

The package has been modified. A few skins have been added to the editor. That is, it is no longer the same package that is installed when one does `pip install <package>`. My understanding is that it now needs to be added to source control and probably added to the project directory, instead of being located within a virtual environment's directory.

The question is what is the way go about this situation most efficiently. Should I add the package to the project's directory or is there a way to somehow manage this through `pip` and `requirements.txt`?

Comment: You can override some functions with monkey patching.

Comment: @NKSM What do you mean?

Comment: @MadPhysicist https://stackoverflow.com/q/5626193/7976758

Comment: @MadPhysicist, See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24668215/6143954.

Comment: Thanks for the instruction! I am still failing to see how this is helpful in my case. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can push the modified library's source to a git repository and in order to install it in your projects, you can make use of PIP's [VCS Support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#vcs-support) to install it via git.

For example

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/username/repository.git
```

requirements.txt should be something like

```
package-one==1.9.4
git+git://github.com/username/repository.git
package-three==1.0.1
```

So you don't have to keep the modified library source in the project directory, and can be installed in any project as a usual package.

Comment: I see. But in this case I take upon the task of ensuring this package is up-to-date with possible developments of its original author, right? Any advice there?

Comment: Yeah sure you have to make sure the fork is updated timely, but there is a way you can automate this task with GitHub actions see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23793062/6562458).