# git procedure to merge branches from origin

Tags: git, svn, github, version-control, merge

I am a member of a Github repository where there are three branches, `master`, `dev` and `deployment`.

I cloned the repository on my local computer with: 
`git clone git@github.com:COMPANY/repo.git`

What I need to do is to merge the changes that were pushed in the `dev branch` into the `master branch`, and then the `master branch` into the `deployment branch`. My issue is that I only see the `master branch` on my local clone.

The way I tried to do what is required is as follows:

1. I created a `dev branch` and a `deployment branch` on my local repository with: `git checkout -b dev` and `git checkout -b deployment`.
2. I pulled the `dev branch` and `deployment branch` from the origin with: `git pull origin dev` and `git pull origin deployment`.
3. I switched to the `master branch(git checkout master)` and I merged the `dev branch` into it: `git merge dev`.
4. Then I switched to the `deployment branch(git checkout deployment)` and I merged the `master branch` into it: `git merge master`.

Is this the right procedure to do it or is there a better way?

How can I push all the changes from the two merged branches back to the origin on Github?

Comment: Take a look at this answer on how to fetch remote branches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches

Comment: There may be issues if you created a branch locally with the same name as the one on remote -- is this the case?  If so, you probably meant to modify the remote branches (that apparently you can't see).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear you have used the wrong order of steps. You shouldn't have created the `dev` and `deployment` branches with `git checkout -b dev`. This will create local branches that branch off of your current branch - this is probably not what you want.

The clean way would have looked like this:

```
# Clone the repo
git clone git@github.com:COMPANY/repo.git

# Fetch everything, just to be sure
git fetch --all

# Take a look at the available branches
# This should list the remote dev and deployment branches in the form 'remotes/origin/dev'
git branch -a

# Now simply check out the dev branch without creating a new branch
git checkout dev
```

Git knows that if there is a remote branch called `dev` and you don't have a matching local branch, that it should use the remote one when you do a `git checkout dev` (without the `-b` switch!). It will automatically create a new local `dev` branch from the remote `dev` branch.