# How to get list remote branches under one username?

Tags: git

I am trying to fetch all remote branches under one user name that are not deleted in git. How to fetch all remote branches created by a particular user in git?

Comment: The answer to your question is in this link: [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches)

Comment: git does not store any information about the user who created a particular branch. Are there any conventions in your case e.g. for the branch names that would allow to detect the user who created the branch?