# Git Hub Clone All Branches At Once

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to clone an entire repository onto my machine using linux. I used

```
git clone <url>
```

I then went into the folder where it was downloaded and typed

```
git branch
```

in the terminal. It's only showing me master and not other branches which were in the remote repository. How do I clone all branches?

I know that for each branch in the remote I can separately use

```
git checkout -b <name of local branch> origin/<name of remote branch>
```

but is there any way other than that?

Comment: `git branch -a` lists all branches. See also `git branch --help`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10312587/166339

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

(1) Inside git local repostitory, create a new sh file

```
touch getAllBranches.sh
vi getAllBranches.sh
```

(2) Insert the below content to `getAllBranches.sh` file:

```
for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master `; do
   git branch --track ${branch#remotes/origin/} $branch
done
```

(3) Get all branches:

```
chmod +x getAllBranches.sh    
sh getAllBranches.sh
```

(4) Check result at local repository:

```
git branch
```

For example, I use repository: https://github.com/donhuvy/spring-boot

As you can see, I have fetched all branches to local machine:

[image]

Comment: Two comments: if one has added upstream already problems, so think the script should be "git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master | grep -v upstream" (remove upstream branches). Also, why the --track? Wouldn't it be more consistent to not use that option, that is, upstream fetches and merges of master would be same as any branch?

Comment: Not needed. See Xiong's answer below.

Answer (score 57):

This isn't too much complicated, very simple and straight forward steps are as follows:

After cloning the repo, run `$ cd myproject`

`git branch -a` This will show you all the remote branches.

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/v1.0-stable
  remotes/origin/experimental
```

If you want to work on remote branch, you'll need to create a local tracking branch:

```
$ git checkout -b experimental origin/experimental
```

Verify whether you are in the desired branch by the following command;

```
$ git branch
```

The output will like this;

```
*experimental
master
some branch2
some branch3
```

Notice the * sign that denotes the current branch.

Comment: I've tried this method. But I only see `master` and `experimental` branches after typing `git branch`. Anyone else has the same problem?

Comment: @Brian I'm sure you've found it by now, but the key is the `-a` switch, i.e. `git branch -a`.

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted, it doesn't answer the question - how to clone _all_ repos at once.

Answer (score 23):

```
git clone --bare <repository url goes here> .git
```

Then after the repo is clone with all its branches then do the following

```
git config --bool core.bare false

git reset --hard
```

Comment: this worked for me but with `--mirror` instead of `--bare`. Remotes can be restored using: `for branch in $( git branch -a | sed 's/^..//' ); do git checkout $branch; git branch --set-upstream-to=$branch $branch; done
` (for some reason `$( git branch -a )` adds files in the current directory to the list as well, hence the sed)

Comment: `--mirror` has the same effect as `--bare` . `--mirror` creates a bare repository.

Comment: --bare worked for me better than --mirror, because mirror created a .git file that was basically the hidden file git creates

Comment: `git reset --hard` tells me: "fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree" for both `--bare` and `--mirror`

Comment: @Kirill same here

Comment: `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree` message is because you are not correctly applying the command which written in a clearer way should be: `git clone --bare https://your_repo_name.git your_local_dir/.git`, the following commands should be executed into `your_local_dir`, and it is done.

Answer (score 17):

> It's only showing me master and not other branches which were in the remote repository. How do I clone all branches?

Branches are essentially pointers to commits.  When you do a `git clone` (or a `git fetch`), you retrieve all of the commits from the remote repository, and all of its branches as well.

However, `git branch` does not show remote branches by default.  Instead, it shows you your *local* branches, which may or may not have any relation to branches that exist on the remote.  If you run `git branch --all`, git will report all of the branches it knows about, both local and remote.

It's worth noting that tags do *not* operate this way, and there is no distinction between a local and remote tag.

Comment: Your answer is helpful in understanding, but doesn't; answer the real question of how to get all the branches such that you can switch between them (for us git beginners). The selected answer would seem to do that, but if you have a better idea would love to hear it.

Comment: @DavidH Generally there's nothing special you need to do; `git branch -a` will show the remote branches, and if you check out a branch name that doesn't exist locally, but does on the remote, git will automatically create a local branch for you.

Comment: I'm not in a good place to test right now - I infer that if I see branches like "remotes/origin/experimental", I can then simply "git checkout experimental" and it will do as you say above?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.  If for some reason it doesn't (I think old versions of git didn't used to do that), you can use the longer form version that Amit mentions in his answer, which is `git checkout -b experimental origin/experimental`.

Answer (score 11):

I find this to be the simple solution to clone a git repository and all remote branches:

```
# Clone remote repository and all branches
git clone --mirror https://github.com/test/frontend.git frontend/.git

# Change into frontend directory
cd frontend

# Update git config
git config --unset core.bare

# Checkout master branch
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `git clone --bare https://repo.git projectName`
2. `cd projectName`
3. `git push --mirror https://repo.git`

that makes your repo completely identical.

See: https://help.github.com/en/articles/duplicating-a-repository

Comment: That's the easiest way to copy a repo, bar none!

Comment: Be very careful with `git push --mirror` - it'll overwrite the remote list of branches with whatever you have locally. If you haven't done steps 1 and 2 cleanly, you'll probably be ruining your remotes.

Comment: Don't try this at home

Answer (score 3):

To download a full repository, including all branches, use the following command:
`git clone --mirror <URI>`

This will create a folder called `repository.git` unless you give it a different name.

Now, this gets you a full clone of the original repository, but because it's in `bare=true` mode, you don't have a work tree. Effectively, what you have is the `.git` folder, including all branches and content. This is a fancy way of saying that you won't have direct access to the files because they're stashed away within the git system (compressed, etc).

To make this a "normal" git repo, we need to make this clone the `.git` folder within a new folder, which will be our usual repo folder:

`mkdir <repo folder name>
mv repository.git <repo folder name>/.git
cd <repo folder name>
git checkout master`

Note that there is no single native git command to download all remote branches, so the simplest way is to make sure you have all commits pushed to the origin, and then re-download the whole repository anew using this --mirror option.

Comment: This mostly worked for me, except `git checkout master` failed with `fatal: this operation must be run in a work tree`. Removing `bare=true` from `.git\config` fixed that.