# How to move Android source code files synced on Windows machine with Cygwin to PC running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, git, ubuntu

Firstly, I got two questions to ask. My first question is I've downloaded repo tool for Windows and within Cygwin terminal used the below command

```
repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-14.0 --depth=1
```

to get CyanogenMod android source files and later used the below command
`repo sync` .

Now I want to move my local repository and source files to another machine that runs on Ubuntu 14.04. How to achieve this? Does a simple simply copying of files will make the repo work on Ubuntu? I have very limited bandwidth for PC running ubuntu so I don't prefer to download the entire files again in Ubuntu.

Now my second question is, there is new branch cm-14.1 so how do I update my local branch on Ubuntu after moving the files?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(Before all, you should fetch all branches to local machine, this is steps-by-steps tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40318872/3728901)

Use `git bundle` (for backup all branches)

A real example: On Windows OS PC

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/donhuvy/personal_finance.git
cd personal_finance.git/
git bundle create repo.bundle --all
```

`repo.bundle` is the file what you need (full back up) in the same directory.

How to restore from file `repo.bundle` (On Ubuntu OS PC):

```
git clone repo.bundle
```

Reference

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle

http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/tips-and-tricks#bundle-the-repository