# How to create git local branch except master

Tags: git, github

I want to create local branches for all existing remotes except master one.

I am new to git so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _Why_ do you want to create local branches? You do realize Git already downloads all remote branches to your repo (use `git branch -a` to see them)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch all git branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git command-line, then first use this command

```
git fetch
```

then you can switch to what ever branch you need like

```
git checkout <branch-name>
```

To know branch-names on remote, use this (list of remote branches)

```
git branch -v -r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create a branch with checkout command using -b:

```
git checkout -b <branch-name>
```