# Git: How to get all `remote` branches locally, pointing to their respective `commits` as on remote?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-refspec

I recently cloned a repo from remote onto a new machine. The remote has 2 branches `master` & `dev`. After cloning, local has only remote's `master` branch, no `dev` found.

On remote, `dev` has merged with `master` and `master` is like 2 commits ahead of `dev`.

Locally if I create a new branch of the same name `dev`, `dev` now points to tip (same commit) of `master` in contrast to remote where `dev` is like 2 commits behind `master`.

How to get all `remote` branches locally, correctly pointing to their respective `commits` as on remote.

Moreover, out of curiosity, just checking out the `.git` directory and found this line in `config` under `.git` directory.

Can someone explain what does the following line mean `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` in `.git/config`? In particular the role of colon `:` separator.

thanks
dk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch all git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do here is a git fetch:

```
git fetch origin
```

This will bring in all remote branches to your local repository in the form of remote tracking branches.  This should include both the remote `master` and `dev` branches.  Note that your initial clone should have already brought in these branches.  But doing a `git fetch` will update `dev` with the latest information and this is a reasonable thing to do.

If you want to create a local `dev` branch which tracks the remote one, you can do this:

```
git checkout dev
```

This will create a new local branch `dev` which tracks the remote one.

Comment: even without `git fetch origin` if i run `git checkout dev`, git tells `Switched to new branch `dev`. Branch dev set up to track remote branch dev from origin.` so what's the point/advantage of `git fetch origin`. thanks

Comment: @dkjain The clone you did, in general, may or may not have captured all remote branches.  Doing a `git fetch` guarantees that you will have `dev` locally.