# Git pull origin master

Tags: git, push, pull

I've made changes on my local branch, and done "git push origin my_branch_name". When I checkout to master branch, and do git pull, does it pull changes from all remote branches to my master branch?

Comment: No, it pulls changes to the master branch from upstream, not from any other branch at all.

Comment: So, how can I see changes from others branches? @LasseVågsætherKarlsen

Comment: `git fetch` – Read the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fetch all git branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches)

Comment: You merge in those other branches if you want them to be included in the master branch, otherwise you might want to just check out the other branches? It is a bit hard to provide good advice because I don't know what you mean by "see the changes".

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I mean get changes to my local repo? What happens when I check out the others bronches?

Answer (score 1):

When you do git pull it only pulls the changes for the branch you are currently on.