# Branch depending on subfolder

Tags: git, github

In my school we have to create exercises based on API Rest. The repo is hosted on Github. We have each a subfolder and a branch to work on. However, when I wanted to try others exercises, the `git checkout [branch]` didn't changed the branch and no error message was displayed. I had to move into the subfolder to checkout the branch and then add it to my local repo.

Can someone explain why is this happening ? It's not the first git project I work on but I've never seen this behavior.

And is there a way to fetch all branch at the same time ? I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches) but except telling me that the repo is up to date it does nothing...

**Update**

I can checkout any branch from any subfolder, but not form the root folder of the repo. But if I checkout from the root for a undefined branch name, it returns `error: pathspec 'asdkf' did not match any file(s) known to git.`. With a correct name it says and does nothing.

Comment: Do you have separate repos for each of those subfolders?  This would explain your observations.  To see what repo you are in, type `git status` from the Git bash, and it will tell you.

Comment: Have you created git repositories in the subfolders as well?

Comment: No, just made branch from master

Comment: It depends on where the `.Git` folder resides. `Git` commands work where there is `.Git` is present

Comment: .git is only in the repo's root folder

Comment: You might be missing the point when you clone only a single branch (typically "master") is created *to track* the same-named branch in the source repo. All the other branches end up becoming the so-called "remote branches" in the resulting local repo. So, if you did something like `git clone https://github.com/foo/bar` and it contained branches "quux" and "frob", those became remote branches named "origin/quux" and "origin/frob" in the resulting repo.

Comment: To check such a branch out, you do `git checkout -b quux origin/quux` which means "check out a *new* local branch «quux» which points at the same commit a remote branch «origin/quux» points at and make the former track the latter".

Comment: @Sravan, that directory is named ".git" — strictly all-lowercase. You might be on Windows, where that does not matter (unless bites you in the rear in weird cases), but on on case-sensitive filesystems, it does.

Comment: @OnStandBy, read [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) for more background on the asymmetry between your local repository and the repositories it communicates with.

Comment: Reading again your explainations but it's still not fit the issue. Maybe it has change since but here I just did `$ git clone [urlOfRepo]` then `$ cd [clonedRepo] && git checkout develop` and nothing changed, no error message was sent. Still, today I did it at least 6 times, I could checkout without any options and it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one year I come back here to close this question, **if you're experiencing something similar, try to checkout the branch in a sub-folder of your repo**. 
I'm more experienced now and I can tell that I did nothing wrong to cause this issue. Oh and in my classroom I was obliviously the only one to have the issue.

Here's what I did :

1. `$ git clone [repoUrl]`
2. `$ cd [clonedRepo]`
3. `$ git checkout [anyBranch]` > Nothing happened
4. `$ git checkout [non-existing branch]` > `error: pathspec 'asdkf' did not match any file(s) known to git.`
5. `$ cd [anySubFolder]`
6. `$ git checkout [anyBranch]` > Branch checked out without any problems

Still a better issue than git completely ignoring .gitignore