# mirror git repository after cloning and adding changes

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am in the process of migrating a git repository from one host to another. for 3 months, we cloned the project with `git clone` (no `--mirror`), and we started adding changes to this new cloned repo. Meanwhile, the original repository was also being updated with changes. Now we need a smart way to migrate the whole old repository (with all the history), keeping in mind that we have already added changes to a cloned version that we also want to keep

Comment: Would a fetch and merge/rebase not do it?

Comment: what about the git history from the original repository ?

Comment: Assuming the "original repo" is your remote called "origin" you can use `git fetch --all`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches

Comment: the original repo has a different name. let's call it `old-origin`. `git fetch --all` will fetch from both origins, I guess. that should be fine, but then I will just need to `git pull --rebase #(master branch)`, then `git push --all`?

Comment: Just for nomenclature's sake, I think you meant "remotes" instead of "origins". --- `git fetch old-origin` will only fetch from remote `old-origin`.

Comment: yeah both "remotes" I meant :D

Comment: Once the fetch has happened, merge each of your branches with their remote counterpart `git checkout my-branch && git merge old-origin/my-branch`. This is where you should fix any conflicts.

Comment: Definitely don't do `git pull --rebase` on your branches. That will change the history and cause lots of trouble. Follow @evolutionxbox's advice and merge the branches from the two remotes instead.

Comment: thnks guys. i ll try that