# GIt cmd to fetch all branches which has been cut from main branch

Tags: bash, git

I have cut one branch(ABC) from git main branch i.e XYZ

Step 1: clone code from main branch in other drive

step 2:  after that when i do cmd :  **git branch**

could not see the branch name which i cut from main branch

What i can see :

XYZ

How can i see ABC also

Please help

Comment: I guess that by "cut" you mean "create from". *How* did you create the new branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch all Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get list of remote branches, you'll need to use the following command:

```
git branch -r
```