# how to make the red line codes branches appear in local branch?

Tags: git

I am a bit new to git
Now I am trying to pull the git from the gitlab into my own laptop

I have tried `git fetch --all` and `git pull --all`

but the red line branches won't appear in my local one

> [image: image here]

As you can see in the image 
when i type `git branch` 
only 1 branch appear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch all Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+fetch+all+branches

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as `git checkout master`.

Those beginning with `origin/` are **remote branches**, i.e., the local "cached" state of the remote repository. To create a local branch off it is as simple as checking out the "base name" of the branch.

Answer (score 0):

To checkout any remote branch and switch on it in simple step :

git checkout -b local-branch-name origin/remote-branch-name

eg:

git checkout -b yourbranch origin/yourbranch

By this command you can checkout remote branch as well as switch to the branch