# Import into GitLab a git project including all branches

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git server in a synology nas. Now I have installed gitlab into a new server where I want to import all my repositories. As far as I know I have to clone every repository from my git server and import them manually one by one. So I started to clone my repositories:

```
git clone ssh://usuario@servidor/ruta/repositorio.git repositorio
```

Then I move into repository folder, added a new remote for the new server and pushed:

```
cd repositorio
git remote rename origin origin-git
git remote add origin ssh://git@gitlab/url/repository.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

Now I got to my gitlab and I can see my master branch with all its commits. I can also see other commits but my problem is that they are not assigned to any branch.

Here you can see commits graphic generated by gitlab. There should be another branch called desarrollo.

[image: Gitlab commits graphic]

If I try to clone this repository from Gitlab I cannot see all those commits since the only existing branch is master.

Edit: adding `git fetch --all` or `git pull --all` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried `git fetch --all`/`git fetch origin` before pushing? Maybe `git pull --all`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699/10871900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `git fetch --all` or `git pull --all` didn't work at all. It does not load any other branch than master. You can check it out using `git branch` to see local branches and `git branch -a` to see local and remote branches.

The solution was to track all branches, adding some code for that, an run it before renaming origin:

```
# Track all branches
for branch in $(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' | egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$'); do
    git branch --track "${branch##*/}" "$branch"
done
# Pull fetched branches, just in case
git fetch --all
git pull --all
```

Then rename origin, as usual, and push everything.

```
git remote rename origin origin-git
git remote add origin ssh://git@gitlab/url/repository.git
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```

With all this done, you can check gitlab and you'll see al branches synced.

Solution for fetching all branches seen here: [How to fetch all Git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312521/how-to-fetch-all-git-branches)

Comment: I'm still reading through the other answer -- I went through same thing as you, I am wondering if I can bring in the branches from my original repo after the fact, since master in my new repo now has changes not in the original repo. I am thinking I'd not push with --all, for one thing.

Comment: I don't think you can add those old commits if you have newers already pushed. All you can do is create a new branch and push your old commits there. Also, you can make a new repo, add first your old commits and then the new ones.