# Git add branches from svn to remote

Tags: git, svn, version-control, migration, branch

### TL;DR

I want to not only move the trunk, but also all branches to the `git` remote I'm migrating from SVN to.

---

We have an SVN repository with a lot of branches which we want to migrate to `git`. For test (and demonstrational) purposes I have set up a small SVN repository that I'm now migrating to `git`. Therefore I started with

```
$ git svn init -t tags -T trunk -b branches --prefix=svn_origin/ svn://localhost/
$ git svn fetch
```

This successfully created a local git repo containing the trunk of the SVN repo. However, there was only one local branch:

```
$ git branch
* master
```

But `git` still knew about the other branches:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/svn_origin/Branch%2001
  remotes/svn_origin/trunk
```

As I don't care about the local repository for now, I then wanted to push these remote branches to the new `git` remote - so, after creating the remote repo and pushing my master branch to it, I tried:

```
$ git push --all
Everything up-to-date
```

So this obviously didn't work. I then tried:

```
$ git push origin '*:*'
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 441 bytes | 220.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), done.
To https://github.com/MetaColon/SVN.git
 * [new branch]      origin/master -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      svn_origin/Branch%2001 -> svn_origin/Branch%2001
 * [new branch]      svn_origin/trunk -> svn_origin/trunk
```

On first glance it seems as if it worked, but the truth is that no branch was created in my remote repo - instead the branches seem to have been pushed to `svn_origin` instead of `origin` (which is my `git` repo).

I then tried something I had found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10312587/7700150) for fetching all branches to my local repo (I could then push them to my remote):

```
$ git branch -r | grep -v '\->' | while read remote; do git branch --track "${remote#svn_origin/}" "$remote"; done
Branch 'origin/master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'svn_origin/Branch%2001' is not a branch.
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'svn_origin/trunk' is not a branch.
```

This only fetched the `master` branch, which I already had. That seems to be caused by the SVN remote not being a normal remote:

```
$ git remote
origin
```

It is at that point that the only remaining option seems to be checking out each branch manually (or via a script) and then pushing all branches from the local repository. But surely there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script that seems to do the job:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

identifier="svn_origin/"
idLen=`expr ${#identifier} + 3`

git branch -r | grep $identifier | cut -c $idLen- | while read branch; do
    echo "Branch is $branch"
    echo "Executing git checkout -b $branch $identifier$branch"
    git checkout -b $branch $identifier$branch
done

echo "Pulled all branches..."

echo "Checking out master"
git checkout master
echo "Pushing all branches to remote"
git push --all

read -p "Done - press ENTER to exit"
```

However, this is not quite the *simpler way* I was asking for.