# Done a git clone of a users repository but cannot see the branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am only trying to access a single branch, not all branches as in the the so-called duplicate questions.

Clone another users repository

```
git clone https://ijabz@bitbucket.org/mvmn/jaudiotagger.git
```

When I try to list branches it shows nothing

```
git branch
```

It shows nothing, even though they do have branches.

e.g https://bitbucket.org/mvmn/jaudiotagger/src/generics_refactoring/

I'm trying to access the generics_refactoring branch

Comment: Try `git branch -a`. By default only local branches are shown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+all+branches

Comment: Esp. look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4754797/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7216269/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16563327/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19644027/7976758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch` only lists *local* branches.

To see remote branches, try `git branch -r` (or `git branch -a` for local + remote)

You might also need to `git fetch` beforehand to have fresh references.

Once you have checked out a branch locally, it *will* create a local version, which will indeed appear in the `git branch` output.

Comment: Oka that works. does that mean gitclone only downloads the master branch ? I want on my local machine to switch to a particular remote branch so what would be the command needed to get and  then switch to  particular branch locally

Comment: You can just `git checkout <branch>` (**without** the `origin/` prefix or it will just checkout the commit and detach `HEAD`) and it will create a local version, already set to push/pull to said remote branch. `git clone` does get all branches as remote references, but doesn't automatically create local counterparts for them.

Comment: Wont that just create a new local branch that happens to have same as remote branch, or will that actually get the remote branch ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor It will make the new branch point at the same commit the remote branch points to at the moment of creation, **and** link them for push/pull operations.

Comment: ok i did git checkout origin/generics_refactoring and that has worked, thanks

Comment: Note that you don't usually manipulate `origin/*` references directly at all, because they are meant to track what the remote repository has (i.e. if you commited onto that, git would get confused on the next pull). So the "local branch that happens to have that as upstream" is exactly what you'd normally interact with. And obviously you can never **truly** check out the remote branch, because that's by definition on the remote end. What you have (as `origin/generics_refactoring`) is [the remote-tracking branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).