# How to clone repository along with changes from bundle?

Tags: git, git-bundle

I have a git repository, and a git bundle file. I can checkout the repository, and apply the bundle on one machine. I would like to use this particular machine as a mirror for this repository, along with the changes from the bundle. However when I try to clone it, the bundle changes don't seem to come across.

This is what I do on machine-A:

```
git clone git@example.com/repo.git
wget https://example.com/extra-upstream.bundle
cd repo
git fetch ../extra-upstream.bundle '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/extra/*'
```

This seems to work fine so far - I have the changes I expected.

On machine-B I do the following:

```
git clone git@machine-A:/repo
```

However only the upstream code is cloned, without the branches/remotes from the bundle. What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67699/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/10312521/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+all+branches

Comment: Machine-B clones all the branches that are present in upstream, no problem there. I'm missing the extra branches from the bundle.

Comment: Machine-B clones all the branches that are **local** in the repo on machine-A. It cannot clone branches that are **remote** on machine-A. To list branches that can be fetched run `git branch` on machine-A (without options `-r`/`-a`).

Comment: Right. `git branch` on machine-A doesn't show the new branches. Is there a (reasonable) way to make the main idea work (to make all the changes fetchable from the bundle), or is it a lost cause from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want mention that you want to create a "mirror", clone with [`--mirror`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---mirror), which will get you the remote-tracking branches of the remote repository as well:

> **`--mirror`**
>
> Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies `--bare`.
> Compared to `--bare`, `--mirror` not only maps local branches of the
> source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs (including
> remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec
> configuration such that all these refs are overwritten by a git
> remote update in the target repository.

---

Alternatively, specify additional refspecs for your remote:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/remotes/extra/*:refs/remotes/extra/*'
```

Or fetch them explicitly without any configuration:

```
git fetch origin '+refs/remotes/extra/*:refs/remotes/extra/*'
```

Both forms will mirror the "extra" remote namespace of the remote repository locally when you fetch.

Comment: Hmmm... you mean on machine-A? I tried it on machine-B so far only, but reading your response many times makes me believe that I totally misunderstood that flag, and my previous tries didn't make much sense. Let me give this a try.

Comment: Ahahahaaa.... your last suggestion works like a charm, thanks a lot