git clone --no-single-branch --shallow-since="4 months" gets only one remote branch
I am trying to clone a repo as below
git clone --no-single-branch --shallow-since="4 months"  somegitrepo

the cloning happens fine, but when check
git branch

it only shows one branch
I want to get all the branches in last 4 months.

This is expected. Did you try git branch -a? This should list all remote branches that were cloned as well as that single local branch.

yes git branch -a works, but git checkout someremotebranchname  does not work

https://stackoverflow.com/q/10312521/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+all+branches

"…git checkout someremotebranchname does not work…" What does it mean? Any error message?
