# What is syntax for the Git command to pull from a remote?

Tags: git, github

What is syntax for the Git command to pull from a GitHub repository using a remote?

I'm using Git Bash on Windows 8.1.

I want to update my local files from the repository. I have two remotes - origin and upstream. I want to update from upstream. The branch on upstream, is master.

Q: How do I specify both the remote AND the branch to pull from?

I am not seeing it in the documentation!

If I enter
$git pull upstream

it responds..
"You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line."

How can I be missing something so common? !!

Comment: [How are you missing someting so common?](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

Comment: possible duplicate of [git - pulling from specific branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924002/git-pulling-from-specific-branch)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
git pull upstream master
```

to pull from the `master` branch on the remote called `upstream`