# Why should I specify a branch on the command line for `git pull`?

Tags: git, git-config

I do not want to setup default origin server and do not want to set upstream for branch.

For the `push` command I have configured `push.default=current` to be able run:

```
git push origin
```

Also I want to be able run:

```
git pull origin
```

But get error:

```
You asked to pull from the remote 'origin', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

How to bypass this error message?

Comment: Do what it says, [specify a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924002/git-pulling-from-specific-branch).

Comment: Specify an upstream, `git branch --set-upstream-to=<origin/foo>`. `foo` is the name of the current branch. Another way is to add the flag `-u` in `git push` when you push the branch for once.

Comment: @ThomasJager: `git push origin` also have said that until I configure `push.default` origin. I need an equivalent option.

Comment: @ElpieKay: >`I do not want to setup default origin server and do not want to set upstream for branch`. Just because I have few remotes to work with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have closed off your one option (i.e., you refuse to set an upstream) so you are left with no option: you must specify the branch.  Note that you can write your own tool that does this.

The answer to *why this is the case* is complicated, and philosophical, and up to the people who maintain Git.  Fundamentally, though, we can look at these facts:

- In Git, the `push` verb is not the opposite of the `pull` verb.  As far as there are opposites, they are `push` and `fetch`.  (The `pull` verb means "fetch, then merge-or-rebase", more or less.)
- As close as they are, `push` and `fetch` are not symmetric.  When you use `git fetch remote` you bring commits from another repository into your repository, and then set up *remote-tracking names* to point to the tip-most such commits.  The other repository has some set of branches *B<sub>1</sub>...B<sub>n</sub>*, and for each such name, your repository now has an up-to-date *`remote/Bi`*.

  On the other hand, since you set your `push.default` to `current`, when you use `git push remote`, your Git sends any required commits for your current branch *C*, and then asks remote *`remote`* to set *its* branch *C* to point to that same commit.  There's no qualifier inserted in front of *C*, no `eugen/` for instance, to make it unique to *you;* you ask their Git to set *their* name *C* directly.

  Even if you used some other push setting, you would still, in general, ask the remote to set *their own* branch.  The `fetch` command has this whole name-space dedicated to each remote: you set *your* `refs/remotes/remote/renamed`, not your own `refs/heads/name`.  The push command has them set their `refs/heads/name`.

There's an assumption here built in to Git: *fetch from many, push to one.*  That assumption does not have to hold true, but the syntaxes available, and the remote-tracking namespace system, is built to support it.  When you step outside this system, you must use a somewhat clumsier syntax.  It's your choice how to deal with this (Git has lots of tools).

If you only fetch from one and push to one, you wouldn't need named remotes at all (why bother with an `origin` if there's only one of them?).  Git could even *assume* by default that the branch names will always be the same on the fetch-from and push-to, and make fetch and push work without requiring any upstream setting.  Of course, that would limit you to fetch-from-one push-to-one.

If Git assumed a *fetch from many, push to many* system, it might have a way to do what you want.  But it doesn't (assume this), so it doesn't (have a way to do what you want).

Comment: I did not see any problem why `git` can not use `name` for `renamed` when `remote` is specified. I always use same names on local and remote and really miss this feature...

Comment: As I suggested, you can *write your own command* (to use in place of `git pull`) that *does* make that assumption.

Comment: The above is my best guess at *why*, but to really find out, you have to ask the people who maintain Git.