# How i get latest in git using visual studio code a specific branch

Tags: git

I have 3 branches, develop is our git server ya origin branch so how I get latest get server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git - pulling from specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924002/git-pulling-from-specific-branch)

Answer (score 1):

You can either do `git pull` or you can use `git fetch`.
Difference between these two can be seen in the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Next time please search on stack overflow more thoroughly. These questions are already answered.