# Clone and pull from different repositories

Tags: git

I am using a repo from a private website and want to pull changes from a public repo. The commands look like

```
git clone -b b1 https://private_git.com
# fetch branch dev from https://github.com/repo_name
```

Specifically I want to fetch branch "dev". What is the right command for that?

UPDATE:

I tried the following commands:

```
$ git clone -b b1 https://private_git.com/my_repo
$ cd my_repo
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/repo
fatal: remote origin already exists.
$ git fetch origin dev
Username for 'https://private_git.com':
```

I think that fatal error is fine because at the first time, I clone the public repo and then upload it to private domain. As you see, when I want to fetch the "dev" branch, it asks for user/pass from private domain. I expected to fetch from github.

Comment: See if this solutions works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64769880/6374123

Comment: Change the name of public remote, give some other name. As origin already exist which is pointing to your private repo.
e.g. 'git remote add public-origin <github url>' then 'git fetch public-origin dev'

Comment: If you want to fetch from github instead you need to use the github url instead of the private_git url

Comment: You might need to check what's in the config file from the .git folder. Whenever you clone, the .git folder will be created with the details of the repo from which you cloned. In the config file, you will see the url and the fetch parameters, which contain useful information of the repo you are actually interacting with. You may need to change these to the public repo in order to interact with it.

Comment: Have you seen the fatal error message? `fatal: remote origin already exists.`
Because of it, you are not overwriting or defining anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that fatal error is fine ...

It's not.

A *remote*, in Git terminology, is a short name that:

- stores a URL, and
- makes things easier for you when you want to talk to the Git software that responds *at* that URL.

When you run `git clone`, this *creates a new, empty Git repository* and then *runs `git remote add` for you* to add one remote *to* your Git repository.  By default—and generally you should not change this—this first, and for most people *only*, remote is named `origin`.  So `origin` tells you *where you cloned your repository*.

You want to:

1. clone a *private* repository, but then
2. obtain additional commits from a *different public repository*

and hence you should use *two remotes*, one for the private repository and one for the public repository.  The names you choose for these two remotes are up to you: you can call the private one `fred` and the public one `barney` or `wilma` if you like, or you can keep calling one `origin` and call the other `public` or `private` if you like.

Whether to call the *public* repository `origin`, or call the *private* repository `origin`, or to use `origin` at all, is up to you.  But most people will mostly expect the name `origin` to refer back to wherever you got the repository from and/or wherever you expect to send *new commits*.  Take those two factors into consideration.

Then, if you decide to call them `private` and `public` respectively for instance, you might do this:

```
git clone -o private -b b1 https://private_git.com/my_repo
cd my_repo

# now fetch branch dev from https://github.com/repo_name
git remote add public https://github.com/repo_name
git fetch public dev
```

You will now have two sets of remote-tracking names: `private/*` refer to the private repository commits and branch names, and `public/dev` refers to branch `dev` from repository `public`.  (This assumes your Git version is 1.8.2 or later.)

Note that your `-b b1` in your `git clone` tells your Git software to create, locally, branch `b1` after the clone process.  For this to succeed, this requires that the private repository have a branch named `b1`, so you'll have a `private/b1`.  Since you did not use `--single-branch` or `--depth` options you will have `private/*` names for all other branches.  You will not have a remote named `origin`, which may confuse some humans.